# Can you electroplate edge connectors/pins/pads/fingers with the chips still on the board?

Tags: pins, rom, plating

I recently bought a NES game with corroded pins and I'm not able to return it. I've tried the non-destructive stuff like isopropyl swabs and hi-poly erasers, I've tried less destructive stuff like baking soda and vinegar, and I'm about to progress to stuff that will definitely wear off the copper plating on the pads like acids and solder. Of course, the tin underneath is much more attractive to dust and corrosion, so I'd like to protect it ASAP. I could remove the chips to re-plate the pins, but I'm not confident enough in my soldering or heatgun skills to do it right and not kill the chips with heat. Can I leave the chips on to electroplate the pins, or will enough voltage or current run through the traces to kill the ROM chips?

Comment: To electroplate the pins evenly, you need to connect all of the pins to the plating bath cathode. This will mean they're all the same potential, so no voltage differences on your board, so no danger to your chips.

Comment: The plating is the tin, the tracks are made of copper. If you remove the copper, there is nothing left. Perhaps an in-focus photo of the subject would help.

Comment: If the corrosion has broken the tracks, you can get replacement PCBs where you transfer the components to the new board.

Comment: If it's really bad thick corrosion, get a burnishing pen. Looks like an eraser pen but with fiberglass brush tip and lightly scrapes off the oxide. Not sure what you mean by tin being under the copper though...it's the other way around normally. The copper is the base conductor and tin or gold or nickel is plated on top to protect it. THere's liquid tin solution from electronics store. Not sure how it works but no electroplating needed Probably not as durable though.. https://www.mgchemicals.com/products/electronics-prototyping/electroless-plating/421a-liquid-tin/

Comment: Have you seen this video about fixing it ?   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecoxUwzyc0Q

Comment: @AndrewMorton The appearance of the pins, pre-vinegar, was sort of gold but more orange. The vinegar and baking soda removed some of the gold color and what was underneath was silvery. I don't think it's gold-plated, because vinegar doesn't dissolve gold.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop That looks perfect! I'll try to pick up a kit like that or similar to protect the pins after I remove the corrosion.

Answer (score 1):

If it's from corrosion, there probably isn't much you can do as it's likely from salts and it's hard to get rid of salts.

If it's from oxidation, use some [deoxit](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=deoxit) or other contact cleaner.

> Can I leave the chips on to electroplate the pins, or will enough
> voltage or current run through the traces to kill the ROM chips

It's unlikely that you could plate the PCB with the parts on, electroplating usually involves a voltage on whatever you are plating. The parts would also get plated.
There are also many chemicals used and the PCB is submerged.

Comment: I wasn't planning on submerging the entire part in plating solution - Just up to the edge connectors. I'll check out this deoxit stuff. Also, is oxidation not a form of corrosion? What I'm seeing is some dark brown/blackish stuff on the pins. Some of it came up with a fingernail, but most of it needs something heavier-duty.

Comment: Also tech spray pcb cleaner gets most residue off of pcbs and it's safe for most components.